Bootstrap js is not applied
I run this command to add bootstrap in rails 7 application
It added css but when click on dropdown it's not working. same for navbar button when we shrink the screen

It pinned in my importmap
but it's not working any idea why?
# Pin npm packages by running ./bin/importmap

pin "application"
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js"
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js"
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js"
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
pin "bootstrap" # @5.3.3
pin "@popperjs/core", to: "@popperjs--core.js" # @2.11.8

How to apply bootstrap in rails

Hi Palash, which command(s) did you mean, please? Could you show us the code instead of trying to give a screenshot of it?
